# Sorting a dictionary by value that is read in through JSON file

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

So I'm trying to sort a `Dictionary` alphabetically by last names, and all the data is read in from a JSON file. I tried putting
`let sortedRoster = students.studentsRoster.sorted { $0.last_name < $1.last_name }`
in the controller, but I was getting an error saying that.
`'[String:AnyObject]' has no member 'last_name'.`

Could someone help me out or point me in the right direction please?

**StudentRosterModel**

```
func readJsonFile()
{
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("student_roster", ofType: "json"){
        do
        {
            let jsonData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            do
            {
                let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try
                    NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options:
                        NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                if let students : [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] = jsonResult["students"] as? [Dictionary]
                {
                    studentsRoster = students
                }

            } catch {}
        } catch{}
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you created a model class for student?

Comment: Sorting a dictionary is kinda pointless, it's key:value not indexed, just parse it to your student object array first then sort

Comment: 1) Don't use `MutableContainers` in Swift as you only read the object, 2) Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, 3) Don't annotate types in Swift (unless the compiler tells you) 4) Dictionaries are unordered / unsorted by definition.